# Array[Byte] of Image file PNG convert to JPG

Tags: java, scala

I have array[Byte] of file, saved on DB.
Is there a way to convert it to JPG if its for example PNG ?
And no saving file on disc, just operations on those array[byte]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Read it into a BufferedImage and write it again to a byte array, using JPG encoding.

```
InputStream is = ...;
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "JPG", baos);
byte[] array = baos.toByteArray();
```

For the inputstream (`is`), use either a inputstream that comes straight from the BLOB in your DB, or use a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: Correct, but in Java. The author wasn't very clear if he wants Java or Scala but I assume by the Array[Byte] typing he is using Scala.

Comment: I never used Scala before, but I thought that you could write plain Java in Scala? Scale would be just an extension.

Comment: You can use Java in Scala, and I wasn't criticizing your post, but if you're using Scala you'll typically want a Scala solution first, otherwise what's the point :)